# Unary and Binary Negation

Tags: c++, c++11

The C++1x standard has deprecated the old STL binder functions in favor of the more universal `std::bind`.  However, it seems that `std::not1` and `std::not2` are not deprecated in favor of a universal `std::not_` or something.  The reality is that the `<functional>` part of the STL, prior to C++1x, was really cumbersome to work with due to 1) the lack of lambdas, 2) the fact that the binders and negation functors required a nested typedef `argument_type`, meaning they couldn't work with ordinary functions, and 3) the lack of variadic templates necessitated separate binder and negation functions depending on the number of arguments.

C++1x changed all of this, dramatically improving the usefulness of `<functional>`.  But for some reason, C++1x seems to have improved everything *except* `std::not1` and `std::not2`.  Really, it would be nice to have a standard universal `negate` function, like:

```
template <class F>
class negation
{
    public:

    negation(F f) : m_functor(f) { }

    template <class... Args>
    bool operator() (Args&&... args) const
    {
        return (!m_functor(args...));
    }

    private:

    F m_functor;    
};

template <class F>
inline negation<F> not_(F f)
{
    return negation<F>(f);
}
```

This would of course deprecate `std::not1` and `std::not2` in the same way the old binders were deprecated.

**Question(s):** 1) I've looked through the C++1x draft, and don't see any mention of a universal `negate` function.  Did I miss it?  2) Is there some compelling reason why they added a universal `bind` and deprecated the old binders, but failed to do the same for the negation functions?

Comment: Is `<functional>` even useful, now that we have lambdas?

Comment: @Marcelo, sure it is.  `std::bind` is very useful.

Comment: How so? @Howard's comment to [DeadMG's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567342/unary-and-binary-negation/5567712#5567712) links to [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930903/bind-vs-lambda/4581747#4581747) that argues for bind, because lambdas don't do type inference. Frankly, however it convinces me of exactly the opposite. Using explicit types — `auto f = [](const char* a, float b) { cout << a << ' ' << b; };` — annoying as it is, is vastly better than the bind solution presented in that answer. How often do you think bind offers a superior solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You didn't miss it.
2. Compelling reason? It depends on who you ask.  The lack of this functionality was discussed, but not until very late in the process.  Hmm... I can't find the paperwork on that at the moment, there may not be any.

The best solution for this (imho) is to add operator!() to bind.  But by the time this came up, the committee was in no mood to add new features to C++11.  Perhaps it will come in a technical report.

Oh, here's the paperwork:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3224.html#gb97

Comment: Interesting.  I can't believe the proposition to overload `!` for `bind` was rejected.

Comment: The "at this time" in the response is committee-speak for "we would like to consider this again after C++0x".  Creating a good standard is very time consuming.  Creating a perfect one literally takes forever. <sigh>

Comment: Still faster than fixing a broken one!

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, if not officially, *all* of the old function object binding system is deprecated, since lambdas are a much superior solution. I find it more curious that they bothered to update `bind` and any of the rest of it at all.

Most likely, you will find that this is because the original `boost::bind` did not provide such a `negate` function, and all of the new TR1/C++0x binding mechanism is based on that, and nobody noticed that `not` was missing.

Comment: The committee does not consider bind to be obsolete.  Here's a good SO answer as to why:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930903/bind-vs-lambda/4581747#4581747

Comment: @Howard: I said "not officially", as in, I recognize that they are not deprecated by the committee.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Funny, I believe that I did. Did I say anything to the contrary?

Comment: Yes, you said it was effectively deprecated and that answer is a counterexample. Sometimes I'll write a reusable functor and want to negate it in one case. Either way, `not_()` performs type deduction which lambdas cannot do.

Comment: @DeadMG: I chose my words carefully in my comment.  Anyone who can read the standard (and you obviously have the skills to do so) can clearly see bind isn't deprecated.  The information I'm giving is that there are no proposals to deprecate bind, and no one on the committee is talking about doing so.  I personally asked one of the authors of lambda if we needed to deprecate or remove bind.  The response was remarkably similar to the SO answer I linked to above.  All that being said, we have very little experience with the combination of bind and lambda.  Your view might prevail, or might not.

Comment: @Howard: Formal or informal deprecation aside, how does the answer you linked to demonstrate the benefits of bind? The fact that parameters can't be auto is a straw man, since declaring explicit parameter types is still vastly superior to the bind solution presented.