# Is std::bind still useful compared to lambdas?

Tags: c++, lambda, bind, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bind Vs Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930903/bind-vs-lambda)

My use of `std::bind` had dropped to 0 now that lambdas have gained wide support.

Are there any problems that `std::bind` is uniquely suited for over a lambda function?

Was there a compelling reason to keep `std::bind` in the standard once lambdas where added?

Comment: Bind can still be __far__ more succinct than lambdas if the argument types are lengthy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930903/bind-vs-lambda/4581747#4581747

Comment: They're still pretty orthogonal IMO.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Could you expand on that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17545183/1274850

Comment: "Was there a compelling reason to keep std::bind in the standard once lambdas where added?" usefulness of bind in a world with lambdas aside the C++ standards generally try not to break existing code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can capture by value or by reference, and the problem is that capture by value really means 'capture by copy'. This is a show stopper for a move-only type. So you can't use a lambda to do the following:

```
struct foo { void bar() {} };

std::unique_ptr<foo> f { new foo };
auto bound = std::bind(&foo::bar, std::move(f));
static_assert( std::is_move_constructible<decltype(bound)>::value, "" );
bound();
```

IIRC the Standard Committee briefly considered allowing arbitrary expression inside a lambda capture list to solve this (which could look like `[std::move(f)] { return f.bar(); }`), but I don't think there was a solid proposal and C++11 was already running late.

That and the restriction to monomorphic behaviour with lambdas are the deal breakers for me.

Comment: Nice example! Does the `bind` object end up owning the dynamic `foo` object? Does it itself become non-copyable?

Comment: @KerrekSB Absolutely, on both accounts.

Comment: @Luc great example, I was looking for exactly this. My remaining issue is that that bind expression can't be assigned to std::function<void()>. It can without the unique_ptr and the move though. Is there a way to pass that bind as a callback to another function? (The intention is that the callback owns the object, and deletes it once the callback itself is destroyed).

Comment: @Joao I have my own personal polymorphic function wrapper that, unlike `std::function`, doesn't require the types it wraps to be copy constructible but only that they be move constructible. AFAIK there's no solution available out of the box right now -- I remember some discussion for such a utility on the Boost mailing lists, but nothing has been written now.

Comment: Move capture by lambda was added in C++14, so I think this point is now defunct ;-)

Answer (score 4):

`bind` is great for creating references to bound member function:

```
Foo x;
auto f = std::bind(&Foo::bar, &x, 12, true);
register_callback(f);
```

*Edit:* As Luc Danton demonstrates, this construction is very flexible and allows for the instance pointer to come in a surprising variety of guises (e.g. smart pointers).[/]

If feasible, a lambda is probably preferable, especially since it offers greater potential for optimization, but bind-expressions still have their place.

(In any event, `auto` is preferable over `std::function` for the type to store the callable object.)

Comment: bind is great but lambdas are better.  This `auto f = [&x](){ return x.bar( 12, true ); };` is pretty succinct.  So again, when would `std::bind` be preferred?

Comment: @deft_code: Hmm... `bind` fills in the placeholders at the end (my `f` could still take plenty of arguments), so perhaps that's cleaner when the bind expression is part of a template somewhere. But it's a good question!

Comment: "If feasible, a lambda is probably preferable", indeed, the big advantage of lambdas is they can pick up static stuff statically while a bind picks up everything dynamically. This can often make the difference between a std::function storing the data internally and it being forced to turn to heap allocation.