# Why use std::bind over lambdas in C++14?

Tags: c++, lambda, bind, c++14

Before C++11 I used `boost::bind` or `boost::lambda` a lot. The `bind` part made it into the standard library (`std::bind`) the other part became part of the core language (C++ lambdas) and made the use of lambdas a lot easier. Nowadays, I hardly use `std::bind`, since I can do almost anything with C++ lambdas. There's one valid use-case for `std::bind` that I can think of:

```
struct foo
{
  template < typename A, typename B >
  void operator()(A a, B b)
  {
    cout << a << ' ' << b;
  }
};

auto f = bind(foo(), _1, _2);
f( "test", 1.2f ); // will print "test 1.2"
```

The C++14 equivalent for that would be

```
auto f = []( auto a, auto b ){ cout << a << ' ' << b; }
f( "test", 1.2f ); // will print "test 1.2"
```

Much shorter and more concise. (In C++11 this does not work yet because of the auto parameters.) Is there any other valid use case for `std::bind` beating the C++ lambdas alternative or is `std::bind` superfluous with C++14?

Comment: I thought that lambdas should already be preferred to `bind` wherever that made sense.

Comment: interfacing with foreign (eg. C) code?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz the question is _what_ is that _wherever_.

Comment: Lambdas can be inlined - binds can't

Comment: The C++11 example doesn't even need a `bind`.  Just use `auto f = foo{};`

Comment: Good point. So is there any other use-case?

Comment: @doctorlove Why wouldn't bound functors be inlined ?

Comment: I think that bind sometimes shows "intent" better than possible arbitrary code. Specially if you have an existing function to call. But that's pretty weak as a reason. I think there is little reason to use it in new code.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Scott Meyers gave a [talk](http://www.meetup.com/c-56/events/122753582/) about this. This is what I remember:

In C++14 there is nothing useful bind can do that can't also be done with lambdas.

In C++**11** however there are some things that can't be done with lambdas:

1. You can't move the variables while capturing when creating the lambdas. Variables are always captured as lvalues. For bind you can write:

   ```
   auto f1 = std::bind(f, 42, _1, std::move(v));
   ```
2. Expressions can't be captured, only identifiers can. For bind you can write:

   ```
   auto f1 = std::bind(f, 42, _1, a + b);
   ```
3. Overloading arguments for function objects. This was already mentioned in the question.
4. Impossible to perfect-forward arguments

In C++**14** all of these possible.

1. Move example:

   ```
   auto f1 = [v = std::move(v)](auto arg) { f(42, arg, std::move(v)); };
   ```
2. Expression example:

   ```
   auto f1 = [sum = a + b](auto arg) { f(42, arg, sum); };
   ```
3. See question
4. Perfect forwarding: You can write

   ```
   auto f1 = [=](auto&& arg) { f(42, std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg)); };
   ```

Some disadvantages of bind:

- Bind binds by name and as a result if you have multiple functions with the same name (overloaded functions) bind doesn't know which one to use. The following example won't compile, while lambdas wouldn't have a problem with it:

  ```
  void f(int); void f(char); auto f1 = std::bind(f, _1, 42);
  ```
- When using bind functions are less likely to be inlined

On the other hand lambdas might theoretically generate more template code than bind. Since for each lambda you get a unique type. For bind it is only when you have different argument types and a different function (I guess that in practice however it doesn't happen very often that you bind several time with the same arguments and function).

What Jonathan Wakely mentioned in his answer is actually one more reason not to use bind. I can't see why you would want to silently ignore arguments.

Comment: Is there a way to move variadic template arguments into a C++14 closure? Something like: `template<typename F, typename ...Args>
auto make_thunk(F&& f, Args&&... args) { return [a = std::move(args)] { f(a); }`

Comment: Link to the talk is unfortunately broken

Comment: There is still this that lambda's can't do: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234887/more-ergonomic-convenient-stl-algorithm-calls-sort-order-member-field-ext

Although we can now use `std::invoke` for that. But is it just as slow?

Comment: @Zendel this is actually a good use case for `std::bind` (see https://godbolt.org/z/WpZ6ZU for an example), with the caveat that any template parameters `f` may take need to be explicitly stated when invoking make_thunk.  You should also be able to use generic lambdas in C++14 to achieve the same effect (see @BertR's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17365046)).

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes it is just less code. Consider this:

```
bool check(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
  return ....;
}
```

Then

```
wait(std::bind(check,a,b,c));
```

vs lambda

```
wait([&](){return check(a,b,c);});
```

I think that bind is easier to read here compared to the lambda which looks like a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck

Comment: Note that you can remove the empty parenthesis in the lambda definition.

Comment: They are not equivalent. Your bind captures by value but your lambda by reference. You better not dangle in the latter case!

Comment: Not sometimes, but often.

Answer (score 3):

For me, a valid use for `std::bind` is to make it clear that I'm using a member function as a predicate. That is, if all I do is call a member function, it's bind. If I do extra stuff with the argument (besides calling a memeber function), it's a lambda:

```
using namespace std;
auto is_empty = bind(&string::empty, placeholders::_1); // bind = just map member
vector<string> strings;
auto first_empty = any_of(strings.begin(), strings.end(), is_empty);

auto print_non_empty = [](const string& s) {            // lambda = more than member
    if(s.empty())                // more than calling empty
        std::cout << "[EMPTY]";  // more than calling empty
    else                         // more than calling empty
        std::cout << s;          // more than calling empty
};
vector<string> strings;
for_each(strings.begin(), strings.end(), print_non_empty);
```

Comment: Why use `bind` for that, when you could use `mem_fn`?

Comment: For convenience basically; You can use `mem_fn` for that. I think of `bind` as a "more generic" `mem_fn` (and now that bind has been added to the library I see no reason to use `mem_fn`). Similarly, "why use mem_fn when you can call the function directly"? I think a `bind` expression expresses intent (bind member as separated predicate) better than a lambda.

Comment: Huh? `mem_fn` was added to the language at the same time as `bind`, are you thinking of `mem_fun`?  Your example should be `auto is_empty = std::mem_fn(&string::empty);`, that's simpler, more convenient and expresses the intent more clearly.

Comment: I was thinking of mem_fun (and didn't realize mem_fun != mem_fn). The code does indeed look simpler. TIL ...

Answer (score 1):

Another difference is that arguments to bind must be copied or moved, while a lambda can use variables captured by reference. See example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void p(const int& i) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> f = std::make_unique<int>(3);

    // Direct
    p(*f);

    // Lambda ( ownership of f can stay in main )
    auto lp = [&f](){p(*f);};
    lp();

    // Bind ( does not compile - the arguments to bind are copied or moved)
    auto bp = std::bind(p, *f, std::placeholders::_1);
    bp();
}
```

Not sure if it's possible to workaround the issue to use bind above without changing the signature of `void p(const int&)`.

Comment: We can use `std::ref` and `std::cref`

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding @BertR's comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17365046/912236) to something testable, though I confess I couldn't quite get a solution using std::forward<> to work.

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
using namespace std::string_literals;

struct F {
    bool        operator()(char c, int  i) { return c == i;  };
    std::string operator()(char c, char d) { return ""s + d; };
};

void test() {
    { // using std::bind
        auto f = std::bind(F(), 'a', std::placeholders::_1);
        auto b = f(1);
        auto s = f('b');
    }
    { // using lambda with parameter pack
        auto x = [](auto... args) { return F()('a', args...); };
        auto b = x(1);
        auto s = x('b');
    }
}
```

Test at [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/kyxmHW)