# How to indicate the overloaded function of given signature in std::bind?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdbind

I have api function `f_api(std::function<void(int)> func)` and now I have my process class

```
class Func {
public:
    void operator()(int i) {
        // do some work
    }
    int operator()(int i, int j) {
        // do some other work
    }
};
```

and I want use `Func f` f(int i) to pass to f_api to do the work; so I use std::bind

```
Func f;
std::function<void(int)> func = std::bind(&Func::operator(), &f, std::placeholders::_1);
f_api(func);
```

but HERE the problem, How can I indicate which `Func::operator()()` I want to bind? I can give a member function by its name, but how can I process this when this member function do have several different signed reloading functions? Will std::bind find me the most suitable function to be called? C++ is so complicated.....

the minimal verifiable case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Func {
public:
    void operator()(int i) {
        // do some work
        cout << "i is: " << i << endl;
    }
    int operator()(int i, int j) {
        // do some other work
    }
};

void f_api(function<void(int)> f) {
    f(3);
}

int main () {
    Func f;
    std::function<void(int)> func = std::bind(&Func::operator(), &f, std::placeholders::_1);
    f_api(func);
    return 0;
}
```

the compiling error:

```
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:23:91: error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, Func*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&)’
     std::function<void(int)> func = std::bind(&Func::operator(), &f, std::placeholders::_1);
                                                                                           ^
a.cpp:23:91: note: candidates are:
In file included from a.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1655:5: note: template<class _Func, class ... _BoundArgs> typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__or_<std::is_integral<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type>, std::is_enum<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type> >::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...)
     bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1655:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
a.cpp:23:91: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Func’
     std::function<void(int)> func = std::bind(&Func::operator(), &f, std::placeholders::_1);
                                                                                           ^
In file included from a.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1682:5: note: template<class _Result, class _Func, class ... _BoundArgs> typename std::_Bindres_helper<_Result, _Func, _BoundArgs>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...)
     bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1682:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
a.cpp:23:91: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Result’
     std::function<void(int)> func = std::bind(&Func::operator(), &f, std::placeholders::_1);
                                                                                           ^
```

And in my case it's a little bit different cause my `class Func` cannot be assigned cause one member field of that class is not assignable, so I will get a slightly different error during the compiling time.

Comment: Have you *tried* it? Do you get any errors, or does it work as expected?

Comment: I would advice you to forget that std::bind even exists. Almost always a lambda is easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, I do have. when I do the `f_api(func)`. it shows me the error about function objects assignment incompatible or so

Comment: @kay if he's limited to C++11 or  0x then he must have preference to lambda's in certain cases. Plus implementation of some compilers prompt  bind usage. Eg. ANY Microsoft compiler after 2012.

Comment: That is very relevant information and should be included in the question body (together with the errors). Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you haven't done it yet.

Comment: @kay You can't pass a lambda with capture as a pointer or something, I can't determine which function or how many function will be called, cause I am writing a library here, and I am the endpoint of the code chains

Comment: @LiuWeibo - You can't easily pass a pointer to the result of `bind` either. Furthermore, a captureless lambda can be cast to a regular function pointer. The result of `std::bind` isn't guaranteed to be castable in such a way IIRC.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude At your command, sir

Comment: Please mark and answer with the green check.

Answer (score 16):

You can do it the nasty long way for all overloads. By casting:

```
using sig1 = void (Func::*)(int);
using sig2 = void (Func::*)(int, int);

std::bind(static_cast<sig1>(&Func::operator()), &f, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Alternatively, you could recognize the `std::bind` isn't all that useful if you have lambdas:

```
std::function<void(int)> func = [&](int i) { f(i); };
```

Comment: was discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363003/why-use-stdbind-over-lambdas-in-c14   Problem is that most  popular compilers do not implement lambda's effectively and C++14 isn't supported much.

Comment: @Swift - It's been several years since that post. Compiler support steadily became better. Even MSVC has decent support (and that's saying something).

Comment: @StoryTeller it became better, but not decent. Last decent version is 2012, later ones actually are banned from use by the concern I work for, though test are going on constantly, for each version. working constantly with those, we accumulated about three hundred of use cases where MSVC  generated outright wrong code. some of those you can find on SO. Last versions still support only partial c++11; c++14 ones at whim may fail, lamba code is supported in limited way (that scary "please simplify your code"message). Standards do exist but in real life not everything is allowed to be  used.

Comment: @Swift - My condolences for using MSVC at all. Lambdas aside, Microsoft do support the features *they* proposed well enough. And in case you think I get to use all these shiny toys at work, I'll have you know I'm still programming in C++03 for my living. The latest and greatest is personal interest.

Answer (score 10):

Func is a function object. Rather than taking the member-function pointer, just hand the the entire object to bind, and let it resolve when you use the bind, or in this case when you add it to the `std::function`.

```
Func f;
std::function<void(int)> func = std::bind(f, std::placeholders::_1);
```

or even better, just assign f to the `std::function`

```
Func f;
std::function<void(int)> func = f;
```

Comment: Nice use of the obvious that was staring us in the face :) Only one caveat to note, and that is that this creates a copy of `f`.

Comment: It may be important to notice that in `std::function<void(int)> func = f;` f is copied (i.e. `Func(const Func&)` is used). Depending on your usecase you may want to use `std::function<void(int)> func = std::ref(f);` instead.

Comment: @kay or `std::move(f)`

Comment: very impressive, thank you. std::function<void(int)> func = ref(f); also do the good!