# Connect a Qt signal to a slot using std::bind

Tags: c++, qt

I have many `QActions` and I would like to connect their `triggered(bool)` signal to a specific slot which gets an integere number as input, let's say `setX(int x)`. I need to specify `x` in connect callback. For example:

```
connect(actionV, &QAction::triggered,
        this, &TheClass::setX /* somehow x=10 */);
```

I tried using `std::bind` and it does not work:

```
connect(actionV, &QAction::triggered,
        std::bind(this, &TheClass::setX, 10));
```

Comment: To begin with, you use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) wrong. The first argument is the "function" that should be called.

Comment: For this, I prefer lambdas and it's working fine (especially if receiver is not a `QObject`). e.g. `QObject::connect(actionV, &QAction::triggered, [&](bool) { setX(10); });`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363003/why-use-stdbind-over-lambdas-in-c14/17545183 If you use C++14, you should avoid `std::bind` altogether.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh... Yes it is wrong indeed (: Passing this as second argument, now works. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this easily using a lambda:

```
connect(actionV, &QAction::triggered, [&] { 
   m_theClass.setX(10);
});
```

Comment: Missing `);` at the end

Comment: added the missing ) :)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you used for `std::bind` was incorrect, that's why it didn't compile.

While using a lambda is faster, I am going to post some examples using `std::bind` for completeness shake in the hope of being helpful to other programmers as well.

Example A:

```
// Declaration somewhere in a header file.
void setX(int x);

/*
 * In a cpp file:
 * Notice the order of the arguments. 
 * a) The pointer to the class member
 * b) the instance of the class (in this case is "this")
 * c) The arguments to the function are the rest.
 */
connect(actionV, &QAction::triggered, this, std::bind(&MyClass::setX, this, 10));
```

Now, let's *pretend* that you must capture the parameter of a `signal`. In this case it's a `bool`. I have to remind you, that the signature is `void QAction::triggered(bool checked = false)`.

Example B:

```
// Again, declaration in a header file.
void setX(bool c, int x);

/*
 * In a cpp file:
 * Notice how the emmited bool value is captured with
 * std::placeholders::_1 and then you pass 10 as well.
 */
connect(actionV,
        &QAction::triggered,
        this,
        std::bind(&MyClass::setX, this, std::placeholders::_1, 10));
```

To make this even more extreme, let's pretend once again that you have two overloads of `setX`.

Example C:

```
// Declaration in a header file
void setX(bool x, int x);
void setX(int x);

/*
 * In your .cpp file:
 * a) Choose the first signature
 * b) Choose the second signature
 */
connect(actionV,
        &QAction::triggered,
        this,
        std::bind(qOverload<bool, int>(&MyClass::setX),
                  this, std::placeholders::_1, 10));
// OR

connect(actionV,
        &QAction::triggered,
        this,
        std::bind(qOverload<int>(&MyClass::setX), this, 10));
```

But the `qOverload` macro needs at least a C++14 capable compiler though. You don't want to go to:

```
connect(actionV,
        &QAction::triggered,
        this,
        std::bind(static_cast<void(MyClass::*)(bool, int)>(&MyClass::setX),
                  this,
                  std::placeholders::_1,
                  10));
```

I hope I helped a bit to clarify the syntax. I can't stress enough though that using a lambda is more efficient and simple and that this was just a fun "exercise".