# How to store any kind of function in a variable in C++?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

How would I go about storing any type of function with any number of arguments in a variable?
Something like this:

```
int add(int i, int j) {
return i + j;
}

template<typename Function, typename... Args>
class Class {
private:
    std::function<Function(Args...)> function;
public:
    Class(Function _function, Args... _args) {
        Now what?
    }
};

int main() {
    Class test(add, 1, 2);
    test.function();
}
```

Comment: What do you plan to do with said collection of functions? How do you intend to call them?

Comment: Just like I've demonstrated in the main function.

Comment: @user686368 That is not really what you want. We are trying to determine if you are not actually trying to solve an XY problem here.

Comment: @user686368 I meant more generally. If you really just needed to call one function once you'd simply write `add(1, 2)`. You should explain your constraints.

Comment: This is just a simple example to illustrate my question. The class would have a lot more functionality and the function would be just one facet of it.

Comment: Yes, and I'm asking what that functionality is.

Comment: The class will be a button and the function will be used when you press the button. The other functionality will be stuff like position, depth, frame and other stuff like that.

Comment: Okay, yep, this is a good approach then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `bind` is for!

Your `Class` is effectively just `std::bind`. Let's imagine that you have further use for it, and make it wrap the `std::bind` logic. So we need to store a `std::function` that accepts no further arguments, and returns (in this case) `int`… but we'll make it generic (`ReturnType`).

Then during initialisation you "bind" the arguments with which you constructed `Class`, and forward them into the `std::function` (the use of `std::forward` permitting move semantics for more complex argument types).

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int add(int i, int j)
{
    return i + j;
}

template <typename Function, typename... Args>
class Class
{
private:
    using ReturnType = std::invoke_result_t<Function, Args...>;
    std::function<ReturnType()> function;

public:
    Class(Function _function, Args... _args) 
        : function(std::bind(_function, std::forward<Args>(_args)...))
    {}

    auto Call()
    {
        return function();
    }
};

int main() {
    Class test(add, 1, 2);
    std::cout << test.Call() << '\n';
}

// Output: 3
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/242d14a25d290a7e))

Or, if you don't need `Class` to do anything more, it's just:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int add(int i, int j)
{
    return i + j;
}

int main()
{
    auto func = std::bind(add, 1, 2);
    std::cout << func() << '\n';
}

// Output: 3
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fc246f7ba29017d))

---

#### Bootnote

Your `std::function<Function(Args...)>` type is wrong because `Function` is the type of the whole function, but you've used it like a return type.

Comment: -1: never use bind in generic code.  If arguments are bind expressions/placeholders things go completely crazy in a way that nobody who hasn't implemented bind is likely to understand.  Having an explosive corner case for no good reason is a bad idea in beginner, intermediate or advsnced C++ code; and avoiding it with bind is a real pain.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I haven't implemented bind yet I've never had any trouble of the kind you refer to. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What happens if you pass the result of `std::bind` to `std::bind`?   "If the stored argument arg is of type T for which std::is_bind_expression<T>::value == true (for example, another bind expression was passed directly into the initial call to bind), then bind performs function composition" -- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind -- your example code above passes generic arguments to `std::bind`, which means that the placeholder/composition code kicks in, and that can break in ridiculous ways.

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

template<typename Function, typename... Args>
class Class {
private:
    Function function_;
    std::tuple<Args...> args;
public:
    Class(Function _function, Args... _args) :  
        function_ { std::forward<Function>(_function) } ,
        args{std::forward<Args>(_args)...}
    {}

    auto function()
    {
        return std::apply(function_,args);
    }
};

int main() {
    Class test(add, 1, 2);
    std::cout<< test.function() << std::endl ;
}
```

Demo : https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZqFSSN2K5HU9HMRm

Comment: Reinvents `std::function`!

Comment: Well, didn't think of bind. The upside of my solution is that he may change the parameters later. But I agree your solution is better.

Comment: My solution can rebind just like yours

Comment: Needs to initialize tuple directly, not with `_`.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class R>
struct Class {
  std::function<R()> function;
  template<class F, class...Args>
  Class( F&& f, Args&&...args ):
    function(
      [
        f=std::forward<F>(f),
        tup=std::make_tuple( std::forward<Args>(args)... )
      ]
      ()->R
      {
        return std::apply(f,tup);
      }
    )
  {} // ctor body
};
template<class F, class...Args>
Class( F, Args... )-> Class< std::invoke_result_t< F const&, Args const&... > >;
```

there.

```
int main() {
  Class test(add, 1, 2);
  test.function();
}
```

note that my `Class` type only depends on the return type.

Answer (score 1):

In c++11 and higher you can use Lambda closures.They do exactly what you describe.

For example:

```
int a = 1; 
int b = 2;
int c = [a, b]{ return a + b; }
```

Is equal to:

```
struct TestFunctor {
  int a;
  int b;
  TestFunctor(int a, int b):a(a), b(b){}
  int operator()(){return a+b;}
};

int a = 1; 
int b = 2;
int c = TestFunctor(a,b)();
printf("%d\n", c);
```

Lambda can be converted to std::function and called at any time...
For example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/1RQUF3UUrsgRdJ42

Comment: This doesn't compile. You're storing the result, not the actual functor. And since the question is about how best to store things... (though a `template <CallableType> Class { CallableType func; };` with a stored `CallableType` that you can initialise from a lambda _is_ a good idea! Hit me up when you've made the corrections...)

Comment: In source example lambda also not stored to any place :)

Here is what i mean: https://wandbox.org/permlink/SOVKItI2VNNA5FK6

Comment: Hm maybe i describe not good. Main idea is that if you need to call some function with some variable number of parameters - you can use function that initialized from lambda for that.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not good since `std::bind` can totally be replaced with lambda, using `std::bind` is old-fashioned in modern c++ and may cause some performance issue since `std::function`'s construction is kind of heavy.

[[ see **Why use std::bind over lambdas in C++14?**
]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363003/why-use-stdbind-over-lambdas-in-c14/17545183)

Let me introduce c++20 [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front), this function is intended to replace `std::bind`:

```
int add(int i, int j, int k) {
    return i + j + k;
}

auto f1 = std::bind_front(add, 1);
auto f2 = std::bind_front(add, 1, 2);
auto f3 = std::bind_front(add, 1, 2, 3);
// all will print '6'
std::cout << f1(2, 3) << '\n';
std::cout << f2(3) << '\n';
std::cout << f3() << '\n';
```

And don't forget to include the `<functional>` header :)