# Boost.Asio lambda capture failed to compile

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I found that I can't move an Asio socket object
`boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&&` to a lambda for the `boost::asio::write()` function. I trim the case into a test program below in order to try the compiler results.

If I uncomment the `boost::asio::write(sock,...` line, both clang and gcc blamed that there is no `sock.write_some()` method... but `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::write_some()` is available from the library!

The test code:

```
// to build:
// clang++ -Wall -std=c++17 -o test_asio_lambda_clang test_asio_lambda.cpp
// g++-9 -Wall -std=c++17 -o test_asio_lambda_gcc test_asio_lambda.cpp

#include<boost/asio.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>

int main()
{
  auto foo=[](boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket s){
    auto bar=[&s,sock{std::move(s)}](){

      std::cout<<"std::is_same<decltype(sock),decltype(s)>::value = "<<std::is_same<decltype(sock),decltype(s)>::value<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<"std::is_same<decltype(sock),boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>::value = "<<std::is_same<decltype(sock),boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>::value<<std::endl;

      //boost::asio::write(sock,boost::asio::buffer(std::string{"Hello, folk!\n"}));
    };


    bar();
  };

  boost::asio::io_context io_context;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock{io_context};
  foo(std::move(sock));
}
```

So, I comment out this line and check the type using `std::is_same` to test the type as I think that the type of `sock` and `s` should be sort of `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` and the code `boost::asio::write(sock,...)` should compile.

The result of clang and gcc are different!

I have no idea what's wrong... my coding problem, compiler error, boost.asio error?

```
$ ./test_asio_lambda_clang 
std::is_same<decltype(sock),decltype(s)>::value = 1
std::is_same<decltype(sock),boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>::value = 1
$ ./test_asio_lambda_gcc
std::is_same<decltype(sock),decltype(s)>::value = 0
std::is_same<decltype(sock),boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>::value = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::asio::write` takes `sock` by non-const reference. It means that `sock` is affected by this function.

`sock` is data member of closure generated by lambda. By default, function call operator of closure is marked as `const`. So you are allowed only to pass `sock`  to other *const* functions.

If you want to let lambda modify `sock` you have to add `mutable` keyword:

```
auto bar=[&s,sock{std::move(s)}]() mutable {
```

Comment: Thank you! That's why the compiler complains no write_some() as it is not const.

BTW, regarding asio programming, its better to use lambda or `std::bind`?

Comment: @VictorTsang It is hard to say which one is better. They both do the same job. [Under this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363003/why-use-stdbind-over-lambdas-in-c14/17545183) is nice summary about *bind vs lambda*, it doesn't strictly concern a use in Asio, but it is worth reading.