# Why use `std::bind_front` over lambdas in C++20?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, stdbind, bind-front

As mentioned in a similarly worded question ([Why use bind over lambdas in c++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363003/why-use-stdbind-over-lambdas-in-c14)) The answer was - no reason (and also mentioned why it would be better to use lambdas).

My question is - if in C++14 there was no longer a reason to use bind, why did the standards committee found it necessary to add [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) in C++20?

Does it now have any new advantage over a lambda?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`bind_front` binds the first X parameters, but if the callable calls for more parameters, they get tacked onto the end. This makes `bind_front` very readable when you're only binding the first few parameters of a function.

The obvious example would be creating a callable for a member function that is bound to a specific instance:

```
type *instance = ...;

//lambda
auto func = [instance](auto &&... args) -> decltype(auto) {return instance->function(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);}

//bind
auto func = std::bind_front(&type::function, instance);
```

The `bind_front` version is a *lot* less noisy. It gets right to the point, having exactly 3 named things: `bind_front`, the member function to be called, and the instance on which it will be called. And that's all that our situation calls for: a marker to denote that we're creating a binding of the first parameters of a function, the function to be bound, and the parameter we want to bind. There is no extraneous syntax or other details.

By contrast, the lambda has a lot of stuff we just don't care about at this location. The `auto... args` bit, the `std::forward` stuff, etc. It's a bit harder to figure out what it's doing, and it's definitely much longer to read.

Note that `bind_front` doesn't allow `bind`'s placeholders at all, so it's not really a replacement. It's more a shorthand for the most useful forms of `bind`.

Comment: It's worth noting the optimizer benefit that comes from `bind_front` being that much simpler and more restricted than `bind` with all its bells and whistles. Much smaller implementation that should be easy for the optimizer to see right through.

Answer (score 47):

The paper that proposed it [Simplified partial function application](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0356r3.html) has some good compelling use cases. I will summarize them here, because otherwise I would have to quote most of the paper, so definitely go check it out:

### Automatic perfect forwarding

Using a lambda would involve `std::forward` boilerplate

### Propagating mutability

In case of storing object by value `std::bind` and `std::bind_front` propagate constness, but in the case of capturing lambda the user must chose a mutable or const version creating problems

### Preserving return type

Using a lambda would involve `-> decltype(auto)` boilerplate on the user side.

### Preserving value category

Like preserving mutability, except now we are talking about lvalue/rvalue and only `std::bind_front` does this correctly

### Supporting one-shot invocation

A consequence of propagating mutability and preserving value category

### Preserving exception specification

This is especially more important now since exception specification is now part of type system

---

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) has some useful notes as well:

> This function is intended to replace std::bind. Unlike std::bind, it
> does not support arbitrary argument rearrangement and has no special
> treatment for nested bind-expressions or std::reference_wrappers. On
> the other hand, it pays attention to the value category of the call
> wrapper object and propagates exception specification of the
> underlying call operator.