# Must I use lambda to pass a member function as std::function?

Tags: c++, std-function

The following code works, but I feel that the line `worker([this](int a, long b, int* c){receiver(a, b, c);});` is sort of redundant because it is repeating the signature of `receiver`. Instead of passing a lambda function that in turn calls the member function, can I somehow pass the member function directly?

```
using callback = std::function<void(int, long, int*)>;

void worker(callback c)
{
    c(1,2L,(int*)3);
}

class Caller
{
public:
    Caller()
    {
        worker([this](int a, long b, int* c){receiver(a, b, c);});
    }

    void receiver(int a, long b, int* c)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::bind` is the classical approach, that avoids the need to explicitly spell out the forwarding signature:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;

// ...

    worker(std::bind(&Caller::receiver, this, _1, _2, _3));
```

C++20 also has `std::bind_front`; it reduces this verbiage, somewhat.

You cannot pass a pointer to a member function "directly". This is because a member function requires a ***specific*** instance of an object whose member function should get invoked. So, in some form of fashion, in some way, you cannot avoid `this`, or some other instance of the object, to be involved in the process. This is fundamental to C++. The only thing that can be done here is to find some syntactic sugar, which is basically all this is, here.

Comment: though `std::bind` is considered outdated and clang-tidy will mark this code with a warning. Also, placeholders: 1) hide arguments' types from the reader 2) hide arguments' types from the compiler thus introducing the need for "manual" resolution which will look waaaay uglier than forwarding

Answer (score 5):

**If you have access to C++20, use bolov's answer.** If not…

Though this still uses a lambda, you can take advantage of an argument pack to avoid duplicating the signature:

```
worker([this](auto... params) { receiver(params...); });
```

This requires C++14 or newer.

Perfect forwarding can be added if you have more complex types and want to avoid copies:

```
worker([this](auto&&... params) {
    receiver(std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest way is C++20's [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front):

```
worker(std::bind_front(&Caller::receiver, this));
```

[Why use `std::bind_front` over lambdas in C++20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807743/why-use-stdbind-front-over-lambdas-in-c20)

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest solution, and it worked in VC++ 2022, but unfortunately the compiler I am using (ESP8266 SDK) seems to be supporting only C++17, and it does not seem to have `bind_front` but only `bind`. So close...

Comment: @DamnVegetables yes, C++20 is pretty new. Keep this solution in mind for the future :p