# std::bind with member function and this in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn C++ and I'm experimenting with the std::bind function of the standard library. As a result, I understood that std::bind allows to wrap a function and to partially apply the function. This works very well with functions that are not member functions of a class. Now I try to use std::bind with class member functions and the 'this' pointer but I can't compile and don't know how to fix this problem. Could someone help me to really understand std::bind ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Class1 {
    public:
        Class1() = default;
        ~Class1() = default;
        void print(std::function<void(void)> function2) {
            function2();
        };
};

class Class2 {
    public:
        Class2() = default;
        ~Class2() = default;
        void test_bind() {
            std::function<void(void)> function2 = std::bind<void(void)>(&Class2::print, this);
            class1.print(function2);
        }
        void print() {
            std::cout << "CLASS 2" << std::endl;
        };

        Class1 class1;
};


int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    Class2 class2;

    class2.test_bind();
}
```

Comment: Don't use `std::bind`, use lambdas.

Comment: Don't use `bind`, use a lambda instead: `std::function<void(void)> function2 = [this](){ this->print(); }`

Comment: Yes sure but why i can't use std::bind in this case ? In which case is better to use lambda or std::bind ?

Comment: @Progear You wrote `std::bind<void(void)>` which is wrong. Remove the `<void(void)>` part.

Comment: @Progear It's always better to use a lambda in my opinion.

Comment: General recommendation is to always use lambdas now. Lambdas can be optimized by the compiler in ways that std::bind cannot and lambdas can do everything std::bind can (in c++14 and higher).
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363003/why-use-stdbind-over-lambdas-in-c14).

Comment: Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the compiler deduce types based on passed arguments:

```
std::function<void(void)> function2 = std::bind(&Class2::print, this);
```

above is enough.

Version with explicit template arguments list looks like:

```
std::function<void(void)> function3 = std::bind<void(Class2::*)(),Class2*>(&Class2::print, this);

// std::bind<void(Class2::*)(),Class2*>
               / \           / \
                |             |---- pointer to type of object instance you invoke member function 
                |--- pointer to member function
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E19fE6)