# Replacement for `std::bind` with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2019, mutex, c++20, lock-guard

I've got code that compiles with Visual Studio 2017 that uses `std::bind`:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex>    m_lock(m_mutex_wait_for_message);
m_cond_variable.wait(m_lock, std::bind(&Logging::is_message_available, this));
std::lock_guard<std::mutex>     lock_guard(m_mutex_pushing_message);
```

We are now compiling using VS2019 and it's complaining with errors:
`'bind': is not a member of 'std'`
`'bind': function does not take 2 arguments`

CppReference.com says ["Until C++20"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Questions:

1. What is the replacement for `std::bind` in the mutex locking code above?
2. What is the replacement for `std::bind`?

Comment: `std::bind` should work just fine. Did you `#include <functional>`? Anyway, you are probably looking for `m_cond_variable.wait(m_lock, [this]() { return is_message_available(); });`

Comment: It only says "until C++20" because there is a new declaration including `constexpr` under it marked "since C++20".

Comment: ` is not a member of 'std` is the error message you get when you don't include the header file

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you're likely missing the header file that includes it. To address your other points:

When cppreference says `until C++20`, note that immediately underneath it says `since C++20`, meaning that the signature of the function changed in C++20, and it is showing both before and after. In this case, `constexpr` was added to the function, `std::bind` is still there.

As for what replaces `std::bind`, since C++14 you can use a lambda in place of every instance of `std::bind`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363003/why-use-stdbind-over-lambdas-in-c14) for a better explanation. Applying this to your code you can write:

```
m_cond_variable.wait(m_lock, [&] { is_message_available(); });
```

In C++20 you can leave off the `()` for lambdas that take no arguments.