# To transform std::bind to std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, std-function, stdbind

See the code below

```
queue<function<void()> > tasks;

void add_job(function<void(void*)> func, void* arg) {
    function<void()> f = bind(func, arg)();
    tasks.push( f );
}
```

`func` is the function I want to add to the `tasks` which has argument is `arg`.

How can I do to use `std::bind` to bind its argument so that it can be assigned to the object of `std::function<void()>`?

Comment: Do not call the function after you bind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I do to use `std::bind` to bind its argument so that it can be assigned to the object of `function<void()>`?

The [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) returns an unspecified callable object, which can be stored in the `std::function` directly. Therefore you required only

```
function<void()> f = bind(func, arg); // no need to invoke the callable object
tasks.push( f );
```

---

However, I would recommend [using lambdas (since C++11) instead of `std::bind`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363003/why-use-stdbind-over-lambdas-in-c14).

Secondly, having [global variables are also not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad). I would propose the following example code. Let the compiler deduce the type of the passed functions and their (variadic) arguments (function-template).

```
template<typename Callable, typename... Args>
void add_job(Callable&& func, Args const&... args)
{
    // statically local to the function
    static std::queue<std::function<void()>> tasks;
    // bind the arguments to the func and push to queue
    tasks.push([=] { return func(args...); });
}

void fun1(){}
void fun2(int){}

int main()
{
    add_job(&fun1);
    add_job(&fun2, 1);
    add_job([]{}); // passing lambdas are also possible
}
```

[See a demo in](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fPfEvPKhn)

Comment: It's so kind of u to offer these useful skills, I can't appreciate you more, thanks!

Comment: @Torch You should upvote the answers that you fin useful. Also, once the time requires passes please accept the answer that solved your issue if any.

Comment: How would you pop and work on tasks pushed to a local scoped `static` queue?

Comment: @JakobStark That is when we required struct/ classes which encapsulate the queue. Here in the example it could be also via function return, `std::queue<std::function<void()>> const& add_job(...`....

Answer (score 0):

Just bind it, don't execute it.

```
function<void()> f = bind(func, arg);
tasks.push( f );
```

Comment: thanks, I thought `bind(func, arg)()` returns an object... lol