# find_if number present in container with given error tolerance

Tags: c++, stl

There is container with numbers and it needs to find if there is a number in container that is equal to a query value within a given tolerance. Is there a way to implement it with similar to find_if method passing for comparison e.g. `bool areEqual(double a, double b, double eps)`?

Comment: Are the contents of the container sorted?

Comment: something like ?http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of

Comment: no the contents are not sorted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use C++11:

```
bool areEqual(double a, double b, double eps)
{
    return abs(a - b) < eps;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<double> myvector;
    myvector.push_back(1.0);
    myvector.push_back(0.0);
    myvector.push_back(2.0);

    double eps = std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
    double value = 0.0;

    std::vector<double>::iterator it = std::find_if (myvector.begin(), 
        myvector.end(), 
        [=](double d) -> bool
            {
                return areEqual(d, value, eps);
            });

    if (it != myvector.end())
        printf("Found value: %f\n", *it);
}
```

Comment: Uh, I'm inclined to disagree, `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` doesn't seem to be a good tolerance for comparing arbitrary doubles.

Comment: @us2012 It depends on what values you are trying to compare. In my case it should work. Otherwise, anoter epsilon value should be chosen. I used `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: is it possible to call areEqual from lambda expression rather than duplicating function contents?

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy Sure, modified the example.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct CompareFuzzy{
    CompareFuzzy(double qVal, double tolerance = 0.0f):m_tolerance(tolerance),m_qVal(qVal){}

    bool operator()(double a) {return std::abs( a-qVal ) < m_tolerance;}
    private:
    double m_tolerance , m_qVal;    
}

std::find_if(container.begin(),container.end(),CompareFuzzy(5.0, 0.5));
```

Use an [old-school functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object), as shown above, or lambda if you use C++11.

Comment: I think it needs to pass a reference to container instead of a single qVal. Since we have a container to find a value inside

Comment: I understood the logic. value to find is passed to constructor and all values from container are passed in () operator

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy I would term it as each, instead of all, but yes that is it. This i essentially a `< C++11` method of doing what the lamda that others have shown does.

Comment: you may use class instead of struct and inherit from unary_function<double, bool>

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy you can, maybe unnecessary though, unless you need it.

Comment: yes, it is not necessary to inherit. however in the literature they suggested to inherit from either unary_function or from binary_function

Answer (score 3):

you can bind the 2nd and 3rd parameter:

```
std::find_if(
   c.begin(),
   c.end(),
   boost::bind(
       &areEqual,
       _1,
       number,
       eps
   )
);
```

also C++11 std::bind should do the trick

Comment: If you don't want to use Boost, you can also use `std::tr1::bind` which is present and older compilers as well (I know it ships with GCC 4.1.2).

Comment: Also, I am not sure if this actually works. Don't you have to adapt the result of `bind` in order to use it with standard algorithms (because it is missing the required typedefs)? See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bind/bind.html#err_modeling_stl_function_object_concepts).

Comment: In C++11, prefer Lambdas over bind, for clarity and readability.

Comment: yes, I would not like to use boost. what is the logic for std::bind?

Comment: there is a comparison function already defined. it would be superfluous to move its contents to lambda expression

Comment: @BjörnPollex standard algorithms need no typedefs on the predicat/comparator function objects you pass them. They just copy and call what ever you throw in.

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy then use a lambda that just calls that function: `[=](double a){ return areEqual(a, number, eps); }` does the same as the bind in the answer.

Comment: @ArneMertz: You are right - the typedefs are only required for composing functors.

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy std::bind is just standardized boost::bind pulled in to c++11 standard. The syntax is almost the same

Comment: A bit more on lambdas vs. bind can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930903/bind-vs-lambda

Comment: std::find_if(c.begin(), c.end(), bind(&areEqual,_1,number,eps)); ?