# When should I use std::bind?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, bind, standard-library

Every time I need to use `std::bind`, I end up using a lambda instead. So when should I use `std::bind`? I just finished removing it from one codebase, and I found that lambdas were always simpler and clearer than `std::bind`. Isn't `std::bind` completely unnecessary? Shouldn't it be deprecated in the future? When should I prefer `std::bind` to lambda functions? (There has to be a reason that it got into the standard at the same time as lambdas.)

I've also noticed that more and more people are familiar with lambdas (so they know what lambdas do). However, a lot fewer people are familiar with `std::bind` and `std::placeholders`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind Vs Lambda?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930903/bind-vs-lambda)

Comment: See See stackoverflow.com/a/17545183/1274850

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's something you can't do with a lambda:

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeType> ptr = ...;
return std::bind(&SomeType::Function, std::move(ptr), _1, _2);
```

Lambdas can't capture move-only types; they can only capture values by copy or by lvalue reference. Though admittedly this is a temporary issue that's being actively resolved for C++14 ;)

"Simpler and clearer" is a matter of opinion. For simple binding cases, `bind` can take a lot less typing. `bind` also is focused solely on function binding, so if you see `std::bind`, you know what you're looking at. Whereas if you use a lambda, you have to look at the lambda implementation to be certain of what it does.

Lastly, C++ does not deprecate things just because some other feature can do what it does. `auto_ptr` was deprecated because it is *inherently dangerous* to use, and there is a non-dangerous alternative.

Comment: +1. There appears to be an item in [Scott Meyers's upcoming book "Effective C++11"](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.cz/2013/01/effective-c11-content-and-status.html): "*Prefer lambdas to `std::bind`*". I do not have enough insight to comment on that, but if you could, that would be great.

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer! There is an article on capture by move: http://marcoarena.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/learn-how-to-capture-by-move/ Hopefully we'll get real capture by move in the next standard.

Comment: C++-14 will fix this deficiency of lambdas.

Comment: @AndyProwl most applicable is this brief quote from the book you cite: "...as of C++14, there are just no good use cases for [std::bind]"

Comment: While I think, that with c++14 you can probably replace std::bind completely with lambdas (and I mostly do) I still like your point about `std::bind` being less powerful and thus stating the intent more clearly.

Answer (score 24):

You can create polymorphic objects with `std::bind` which you can't with lambdas, i.e. the call wrapper returned by `std::bind` can be invoked with different argument types:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Polly
{
  template<typename T, typename U>
    auto operator()(T t, U u) const -> decltype(t + u)
    { return t + u; }
};

int main()
{
  auto polly = std::bind(Polly(), std::placeholders::_1, "confusing");

  std::cout << polly(4) << polly(std::string(" this is ")) << std::endl;    
}
```

I created this as a [puzzle](http://advogato.org/person/redi/diary/255.html) not an example of good code, but it does demonstrate polymorphic call wrappers.

Comment: Yes, in C++14 this is equivalent to the bind expression: `[p = Polly{}](auto t) { return p(t, "confusing"); }`

Comment: @Elliot `Polly`'s `operator()` is clearly const, so I don't know what you mean. The code in the question compiles fine, and so does the lambda expression in my first comment above.

Comment: Apologies. I Stupidly missed the `const`. 'Should've looked closer before commenting.