# Why Can't I constexpr a bind?

Tags: c++, c++11, bind, functor, constexpr

So say that I want to make some `constexpr` functors, I though I could do this using `bind`. Is there something I'm missing? Why can't `bind` return a `constexpr`?

Given:

```
struct foo {
    int b() const { return _b; }
    int a() const { return _a; }
    int r() const { return _r; }
    const int _b;
    const int _a;
    const int _r;
};
```

I want to:

```
constexpr auto sumB = bind(plus<int>(), placeholders::_1, bind(&foo::b, placeholders::_2));
constexpr auto sumA = bind(plus<int>(), placeholders::_1, bind(&foo::a, placeholders::_2));
constexpr auto sumR = bind(plus<int>(), placeholders::_1, bind(&foo::r, placeholders::_2));
```

Is there something I could do to make this work?

Comment: The question is probably now "why can't" but "why doesn't". It probably could, but it doesn't.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think that would make a great answer. Would you mind posting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no technical obstacle to making `bind` constexpr; for example, the [Sprout C++ Libraries](http://bolero-murakami.github.io/Sprout/docs/index.html) have a [constexpr-enabled bind](https://github.com/bolero-MURAKAMI/Sprout/blob/master/sprout/functional/bind/bind.hpp).

However, [implementations are not permitted to add constexpr to function signatures where it is not specified in the Standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/constexpr.functions), and there has not yet been any proposal to add constexpr to `bind` that I am aware of ([Which parts of the C++14 Standard Library could be and which parts will be made constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052208/which-parts-of-the-c14-standard-library-could-be-and-which-parts-will-be-made)). It is fairly unlikely that one would be forthcoming, since `bind` is [mostly superseded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598607/when-should-i-use-stdbind) by lambda expressions, which as of C++17 are automatically constexpr:

```
constexpr auto sumB = [](int x, foo const& y) { return x + y.b(); };
```

Comment: This is great, as it answers my deeper question of why aren't `bind` results `constexpr` when they cannot do captures like lambdas therefor should be fully definable at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

Well, we don't know what `std::bind` returns.  It could probably be made to work but there is nothing mandated to make it work (nothing is defined as `constexpr` in `std::bind`'s specification).

On thing you can do though, if you have access to C++17, is to use a lambda.  In C++17 the `operator()` of the lambda will be marked `constexpr` by default allowing you to do something like

```
constexpr auto sumB = [](auto val, auto obj) { return val + obj.b(); };
constexpr auto sumA = [](auto val, auto obj) { return val + obj.a(); };
constexpr auto sumR = [](auto val, auto obj) { return val + obj.r(); };
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gAv1EhLyybR5vV3s)</kbd>

Comment: `std::bind` cannot return a `std::function`.

Comment: @Yakk Well, TIL.  Thanks for the information.  answer has been edited.

Comment: In case you want to know why, the return value of `std::bind` must have a templated `operator()`, *and* it must have certain properties when passed to another bind expression; `std::function` has neither of these properties.