# tweaking captured lambda values

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I have the following situation:

```
int p;

[p]() {
// really complex and really long code executing outside the main thread
}
```

The lambda object should be instantiated in several places in my code, `p` being captured every time. The problem is, that the code of the lambda is rather long and depends on `p` and I don't want to copy&paste the same code everywhere. I am reluctant to capture by reference, as the lambda is executing in the context of a thread and the referenced object may change. What would be the best thing to do? Could capturing a `thread_local` variable by reference help in some way?

EDIT:

in the end I went like this:

```
::std::function<void(int)> f; // captures the lambda

int p;

run_in_thread(::std::bind(f, p));
```

The reason why I didn't think of this before, was a discussion about the superiority of [lambdas over `::std::bind`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930903/bind-vs-lambda), but apparently they are not for all purposes.

Comment: if the code depends on p, and it's long, and you don't want to copy-paste, then don't use a lambda. Make a free function, and pass it `p` as a parameter.

Comment: then, I'd still have to capture `p` somewhere, duplicating lambda functionality. Remember, the lambda is executing independently of the main thread.

Comment: Just write a functor that holds an `int` data member, and instantiate one with p whenever you need it.

Comment: `run_in_thread( [p]{ f(p); } );` is a drop-in replacement for your `std::bind` call that doesn't behave strangely if `run_in_thread` perfect-forwards to another `bind`.  `std::bind` is often ill advised because it has abstraction leak problems worse than lambdas.

Comment: @Yakk You are correct, but lambda initializer expressions can look weird when `p` needs to be initialized, that's the reason why I used `std::bind`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want clean code you should generally avoid lambdas with large bodies. So the cleanest solution is probably to move your code into a new function which the lambda in turn calls.

```
void complexFunction(int p) {
  // really complex and really long code executing outside the main thread
}

void run() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    runThread([i]() {complexFunction(i);});
}
```

Comment: How about capturing a `thread_local` variable by reference or something like that?

Comment: Unless each thread initializes the value itself, I don't see how that would help you. And if that is the case, then you would not need to capture `p` at all.