# Using std::transform with std::normal_distribution and std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

stl c++11 solution  :

```
auto distribution = std::bind(std::normal_distribution<double>{mean, stddev},
                              std::mt19937(std::random_device{}())
                              );
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(),
               std::bind(std::plus<double>(), std::placeholders::_1, distribution()));
```

Easy range-based loop :

```
for (auto& d : data) {
  d += distribution();
}
```

My STL solution doesn't work as it always take the first number it generated from the distribution. I tried with the placeholder as the 3rd parameter but it doesn't change anything. All of my data is incremented by the same number which is not something I want. I want the same behaviour as the range-based loop.

It this something possible?

Comment: maybe use lambdas instead

Comment: `distribution()` will be called only once in your first code snippet, and the result will be bound to `plus`. However, you want to have `distribution` called for every element. You have to use other semantics. Note that a  lambda will make this easier, e.g. `[&distribution](double x){ return x += distribution(); }`.

Comment: @Zeta, that's what I thought. using a lambda seems the only path?

Comment: @Lorac a fairly [simple one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c10b741e2ac091b4), though.

Comment: @Zeta Please post answers as answers.

Comment: @Lorac Good rule of thumb: never use `std::bind`.

Comment: `std::bind(std::plus<double>(), std::placeholders::_1, std::bind(distribution))`?

Comment: @Barry if I had time to write one … :/

Comment: @cpplearner or even just `std::bind(std::plus<double>(), std::placeholders::_1, distribution)`, since `distribution` is already a bind expression.

Comment: @T.C. Did you really just tell someone to rely on the passing bind-expression to bind-expressions feature of bind instead of just using a lambda that says what it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rewrite your second `bind` as lambda, to get a feeling how it actually works:

```
auto func = std::bind(std::plus<double>(), std::placeholders::_1, distribution())
```

is equivalent too

```
auto d = distribution();

auto func = [d](double x){ return std::plus<double>()(x,d); };
```

or, if we use C++14's initialization feature:

```
auto func = [d=distribution()](double x){ return std::plus<double>()(x,d); };
```

As you can see, `distribution()` gets called only once. However, you don't want to use the return value of `distribution`, you want to call `distribution` for every call of `func`. While it's possible to do that with `bind`, a lambda will make this a lot easier:

```
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(),
               [&distribution](double x){ return x + distribution(); });
```

And in my opinion, that's a lot easier to read than your previous `bind`. Note that `std::bind` (or rather `boost::bind`) predates lambdas. There were [some issues with lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930903/bind-vs-lambda) in C++11 compared to `std::bind`, but with C++14, lambdas are usually a lot easier to handle, read and understand without sacrificing much.