# Using a std::remove_if for vector of non-pointer types

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a vector of objects :

```
std::vector<QueuedMessage> _messages;
```

And trying to remove all objects with erase-remove idiom:

```
void MessageQueue::removeFromQueue(){
    _messages.erase(std::remove_if(_messages.begin(),_messages.end(),wasMessageSend),_messages.end());
}
```

My compare function:

```
bool MessageQueue::wasMessageSend(const QueuedMessage& mess){

            return mess.canSendMessage();
        }
```

And compare function inside the objects class:

```
bool QueuedMessage::canSendMessage() const{
    return (SDL_GetTicks() >= startTick);
}
```

However, I receive this error:

```
error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<bool (MessageQueue::*)(const QueuedMessage&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<bool (MessageQueue::*)(const QueuedMessage&)>::_M_pred (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<bool (MessageQueue::*)(const QueuedMessage&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<bool (MessageQueue::*)(const QueuedMessage&)>::_M_pred) (...)'|
```

Is it a problem that I´m not using a vector of pointers? Or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: `wasMessageSend` is not a function. It's a *member function*.

Comment: `wasMessageSend` in the `remove_if()` call is a pointer to a member function.

Comment: As alternative, you can make `wasMessageSend` `static`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predicate passed to [std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) is supposed to be a unary predicate with signature like `bool pred(const Type &a);`. That means it will be invoked with the element as the argument. But `wasMessageSend` is a member function so, besides the argument, it also needs an instance to be invoked on. So it can't be used with `remove_if` directly.

You can use [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (since C++11) with it like:

```
_messages.erase(std::remove_if(
    _messages.begin(),
    _messages.end(),
    [this](const QueuedMessage& q) {
        return wasMessageSend(q);
    }
));
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I think I totally forgot that this problem can be caused by using a member function as a comparator because I thought that it has a problem with a member function of the stored object not the class storing the vector.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Thanks for the editing! But why 3 spaces for indent?

Comment: @songyuanyao: Why not?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Because I'm just used to 2 or 4. Yes I know it's a personal opinion issue..

Comment: This is why tab-indentation is far superior, so that you can render the code anyway you choose without imposing your choice on other people (much like you can choose the font, and colour). Furthermore, the indentation of your code gains strict and unambiguous semantics (one tabspace = one level of indentation) that could be autonomously interpreted then handled in any way you like. Sadly, that works poorly on the web, so you are stuck with my three spaces. :)

Comment: That being said, feel free to alter the indentation if you like. It's your post!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yes I adjusted it (in my habit); just asked for curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Since `wasMessageSend` is a member function of your class `MessageQueue`, you need to "bind it" to an object (in this case, `this`) using `std::bind`

```
void MessageQueue::removeFromQueue(){
_messages.erase(std::remove_if(_messages.begin(),_messages.end(),
    std::bind(&MessageQueue::wasMessageSend, this, std::placeholders::_1), // bind this
    std::_messages.end());
}
```

Of course, this is not the only way, you may for example define a lambda predicate on the spot... but this method shows how to use a member function as a predicate.

Comment: You may refer to song's answer

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I know that answer works too, but I'm eager to know why you consider it better or say "less antiquated" :). To my eyes this syntax is a bit simpler.

Comment: Looks a lot _less_ simple to me. A lambda expression is very expressive, which is why it was added to the language

Comment: @A.S.H You might want to read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930903/bind-vs-lambda), or the book *[Effective Modern C++](https://www.amazon.com/Effective-Modern-Specific-Ways-Improve/dp/1491903996) Item 34: Prefer lambdas to std::bind* for further infos.

Comment: I respect your opinions but I will always prefer to bind when the predicate is ready, there, but has the only "handicap" of being a member function. Thanks.